# ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified or timeout expired

Tags: sql, oracle

I am making a table for my hw but i keep getting a error

> ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified or timeout
>   expired

Could somebody help me?

Here are the instructions... Create a table KR_ORDER with the following attributes as shown below.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNgW9.jpg
Order_Number attribute is the primary key of the table. Customer_Name is a foreign key linked to KR_CUSTOMER Table. Salesperson_Name is a foreign Key linked to KR_Salesperson table. Choose appropriate data types for attributes

This is what i have so far.

```
create Table KR_ORDER (
Order_Number number(3)constraint KR_ORDER_pk primary key,
Customer_Name varchar2(30) constraint KR_ORDER_fk references Kr_CUSTOMER,
Salesperson_Name varchar2(30) constraint KR_ORDER_fk references Kr_SALESPERSON,
Amount Number(5));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [many already answered questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[oracle]+ORA-00054).

Answer (score 2):

For one thing, you've duplicated your FK constraint names ("kr_order_fk"). I don't think that would cause this error, but it will certainly cause problems at one point.

Try creating your table without the constraints. Once that succeeds, add the constraints with separate statements:

```
CREATE TABLE kr_order (
  order number NUMBER(3),
  customer_name VARCHAR2(30),
  salesperson_name VARCHAR2(30),
  amount NUMBER(5));

ALTER TABLE kr_order ADD CONSTRAINT kr_order_pk PRIMARY KEY (order_number);

ALTER TABLE kr_order ADD CONSTRAINT kr_order_fk1
   FOREIGN KEY (customer_name)
   REFERENCES kr_customer (customer_name);

ALTER TABLE kr_order ADD CONSTRAINT kr_order_fk2
   FOREIGN KEY (salesperson_name)
   REFERENCES kr_salesperson (salesperson_name);
```

This will break the statement up into pieces so you can see exactly what is causing the error.